# Twilio Abandoned Chats and Calls

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-conversations

Is there a way to have a webhook on Abandoned chats and calls in Twilio ?
I can see that these info can be tracked in flex insights, but I want to add a callback event everytime twilio tracks an abandoned chat or call, anybody knows if that possible ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can use the TaskRouter Workspace Callback Event webhook. the event you want is [task.canceled](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/api/event/reference#task:%7E:text=attributes%20are%20changed-,task.canceled,-Task%0ATaskQueueSid%0AWorkflowSid) - as that is what maps to the “abandoned” metric in Flex Insights. https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/api/event/reference#event-callbacks

Note:  we also get that “canceled” event when something goes wrong (not just for abandons), but it’s the closest we’ll probably get. Even Flex Insights doesn’t distinguish between a “real” abandon and a “problem”.

Comment: Thanks, so task.canceled event will give the same exact result as flex insights when coming to abandoned right ? if Yes this will be perfect

Comment: task.canceled is what Flex Insights sees as “abandoned” - so in that regard, the result is the same!